# Where to find the loss functions for manual fitting in tensorflow2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, python-3.7, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to resolve this error:

```
    AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.api._v2.keras.losses' has no attribute 'sparse_softmax_cross_entropy'
```

For context, I'm using `tensorflow2.0` on windows with `python3.6`. 
I am trying to do some quick categorization with `3-axis` data with a label being 0 or 1.

The usual `model.fit()` method does not give me enough control over the data so I am trying to fit the thing step by step in nested loops.

Here is the model:

```
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(3),
            tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(16)),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')
            ])
```

Here's the code I am using for the fitting:

```
    def fit(epochs=1):
        global_step = tf.Variable(0)
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            epoch_loss_avg = tf.metrics.Mean()
            epoch_accuracy = tf.metrics.Accuracy()

            for data_ in SQdatas:
                data = tf.convert_to_tensor(data_)

                for dataslice in data:

                    inputs, label = tf.transpose([[dataslice[1:4]]]), dataslice[4]

                    loss_value, grads = grad(model, inputs, label) 

                    model.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables), global_step)

            epoch_loss_avg(loss_value)
            epoch_accuracy(tf.argmax(model(x)), y)

    train_loss_results.append(epoch_loss_avg.result())
    train_accuracy_results.append(epoch_accuracy.result())
```

When running I am getting the error mentioned in the title, I am guessing this is a `tensorflow2.0` compatibility issue as the `tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy` supposedly exists in 1.3.
If it is what is the replacement? If not, why?
Thank you for your time.

I looked at the appearance of this error by all mentioned that when upgrading from `tensorflow` 1.2 to 1.3 fixes the issue, which just doesn't apply. I have still tried uninstalling `tensorflow2.0`, uninstalling `protobuf` and reinstalling `tensorflow2.0`, it did not work.

Comment: [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/losses)?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I couldn't find the documentation for 2.0 but here it is:

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy